# Play! Scala case class validation

Tags: scala, validation, playframework-2.0, bean-validation

I have a controller defined like this:

```
  def registerCompany = Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[Company].fold(
      errors => Future {
        BadRequest(errors.mkString)
      },
      company => Future {
        registrationService.registerCompany
        Ok("saved")
      }
    )
  }
```

Company is a simple case class

```
case class Company(name: String, address: Address, adminUser: Option[User] = None,
                   venues: Option[Set[Venue]] = None, _id: Option[Long]) {
}
```

so that I can take advantage of

```
implicit val companyFormatter = Json.format[Company]
```

So far so good, but now I want to have validation in the Company class. I've been googling a bit and the best I found was this:

http://koff.io/posts/292173-validation-in-scala/

So many solutions, yet, I'm not happy with any of them. Most of these solutions have known limitations or are a bit messy. I'd like to have declarative validation (annotation based), as that means I write less code and it looks cleaner.

I could mix java with scala and use JSR-303, but it doesn't work for case classes and I don't want to implement Reads and Writes for simple objects.

This is the closest I could find to what I want, but it doesn't support NotNull: https://github.com/bean-validation-scala/bean-validation-scala

Seems a bit like a luxury problem, with so many different solutions, but the truth is that in Java I can get the best of both worlds.

Is there anything else that I could use? Or any work around to the possibilities I'm listing here that could allow me to use both annotation based validation and case classes?

Comment: On the other hand, one could argue that a solution based on implicits like Accord or io.underscore.validation is in fact much cleaner, as it keeps the case classes free of any annotations and also gives more flexibility in using multiple validators in different situations... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by validation.

You gave an example of a validate Json in request body and I think you would like validate `Json request` (with Company constraints) but not `case class Company` (although the topic is called "Scala case class validation"). So you need use [Validation with Reads](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Validation-with-Reads)

For example you may use:

1. ( __ \ "name").read[String] for Required constraint.
2. ( __ \ "_id").read[Long](min(0) keepAnd max(150)) for 0 < x < 150 constraint.

You may implement own `Reads[Company]` and `Writes[Company]` but not macros `Json.format[Company]`

**Update for comment "The difference is that you rarely need to write a custom deserializer, as jackson knows how to handle any object"**

If you don't want implement own deserialization and want use `format` macros, you may implement `Company validation`, but still using `Reads`:

```
val f(company: Company): Boolean = {... company constraints to boolean ...}

request.body.validate[Company](
  companyFormatter.filter(ValidationError("Company validation error"))(f)
)
```

but this constraints will be applied after full Company deserialization.

Don't even know which is better: universal deserialization and "post" constraints or own deserialization and "pre" constraints. But both are working.

Comment: Yes, I intend to validate that the request is valid, but that's simply an extension of the Company object being valid (as in JSR-303). Validation with Reads forces me to write the "deserialization" code and to have to update it whenever a new field is added to the request, which makes future maintenance harder. Maybe I'm still too close to java, but with Jackson and JSR-303 I can have automatic serialization/deserialization for most cases + object/request validation with minimal effort (especially in the long run). I'm hoping scala has something similar...

Comment: I recently learn scala and have never seen the annotation but at the same time learning Java, I often encountered annotations. As far as I understood the essence of annotation is a declarative description of the behavior of a property or method. May this is  just not 'scala way'? May be `Json` and `Reads` is same as `Jackson` and `JSR-303` but with functions as annotations? But `Reads` is more complex thing, is not only deserialization, it may be transformer also...

Comment: Not sure sure if it's Scala way, as it seems more like a limitation. To me, Reads and Writes are exactly the same as a custom deserializer in jackson (at least in this context). The difference is that you rarely need to write a custom deserializer, as jackson knows how to handle any object, unless you want something specific (like transformations). Scala forces you to write a lot of reads and writes. The links in the original post solve the validation issue without the need to write Reads and Writes, but they have known limitations I'd like to avoid...

Answer (score 0):

You could also roll your own, something like this:
https://gist.github.com/eirirlar/b40bd07a71044d3776bc069f210798c6

It will validate both case classes and incomplete case classes (hlists of options of types tagged with keys, where types and keys match the case class).

It won't give you annotations, but you're free to declare different validators for different contexts.